# How to set all Exchange 2010 Mailboxes with a retention policy of "never permanently delete"

Tags: exchange-2010

In other words... no deletion should happen automatically via "Age limit for retention (days)" however, if a user manually deletes anything, it should always be available in "Recover Deleted Items..." i.e. "Delete and Allow Recovery"

It should be the default for all mailboxes all the time...

Do I need an RPT, or a DPT?  Do I need to specify a policy, or the DPT will kick in automatically since setting no policy makes all the mailboxes "untagged" etc...

Comment: I have difficulty to see that as a working solution as storage will get exhausted. I would look to auto-archive the 'deleted folder', so you could be able to put that storage on slow storage, else please see there; http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2011/08/16/retention-hold-and-litigation-hold-in-exchange-2010.aspx

Comment: Yes, eventually it would become exhausted, but for now, I have plenty of space

Comment: Not an answer, but:  You have plenty of space *now.*  Speaking as someone who used to run the Nagios server for an environment with no Exchange quotas, and as someone who's supported a legacy "retain forever!" policy, I think you'll regret doing this.  At least, you will if your company is successful and grows.